# BASH - multiple threads using the same variable

Tags: bash, shell, parallel-processing, synchronization

Lets assume the following situation:

```
function add_to_list
{
    thelist="$thelist $$"
}

for i in $(seq 1 100); do
    add_to_list&
done

wait
echo "The list: $thelist"
```

This obviously does not work as it should, because the threads are accessing the same variable - how should it be done properly

Answer (score 3):

Bash does not support threads. Only subprocesses. And it is impossible to change a variable of parent process in a subprocess.

Comment: Ok, then call a subprocess. So what would be the possible solution here? Use a tmp file to write the data into?

Answer (score 2):

You might use a shared storage that handle concurrent updates, like a database.

Here is an example based on [sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/):

```
function create_table
{
  sqlite3 thelist <<-%
  drop table t;
  create table t(one varchar(255));
  %
}

function add_to_list
{
  sqlite3 thelist <<-%
  .timeout 60000
  insert into t values('$$');
  %
}

function dump_list
{
  sqlite3 thelist <<-%
  select * from t;
  %
}

create_table
for i in $(seq 1 100); do
    add_to_list&
done

wait
thelist="$(dump_list)"
echo "The list: $thelist"
```

Comment: If I copy this to a test.sh script and execute with bash... bash -x test.sh I get syntax errors:
test.sh: line 31: warning: here-document at line 3 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `%')
test.sh: line 32: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: @MikeSamaras Indeed. The issue is indentation should be done with tabs but copy/paste replaces tabs by spaces. Replace the leading double spaces by tabs and the script should run fine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're conflating threading and subprocessing semantics, especially wanting a variable to be updated.

You could use a named pipe like to communicate between the processes.

```
 $ mkfifo mypipe 


 $ cat < mypipe


 $ seq 1 10 > mypipe
```

This makes `cat` print the sequence.

```
bash-3.2$ cat always.sh

while : ; do
    cat < mypipe
done
```

---

```
bash-3.2$ seq 1 100  > mypipe & seq 100 200  > mypipe & seq 200 300 > mypipe &
```

Creates out from `always.sh` 1 to 300 in order.

I'm unsure whether multiple processes writing to the same named pipe are synchronised safely.